# How to extract numbers just succeeding a unicode character with regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I have the following file name sample:

./data/DDT - T = 10 K/DDT - T = 10 K - φ = 1.0/DDT - T = 10 K - φ = 1.0 - DCT 0/DDT - Result - T = 10 K - φ = 1.0 - DCT 10-40 - t = 1000 s.dat

And I am trying to extract the value of φ using regex in Python with the code:

```
import numpy as np
import re
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

file_names = []
file_name_1 = str(u'./data/DDT - T = 10 K/DDT - T = 10 K - \u03C6 = 1.0/DDT - T = 10 K - \u03C6 = 1.0 - DCT 0/DDT - Result - T = 10 K - \u03C6 = 1.0 - DCT 10-40 - t = 1000 s.dat')
file_name_2 = str(u'./data/DDT - T = 10 K/DDT - T = 10 K - \u03C6 = 1.0/DDT - T = 10 K - \u03C6 = 1.0 - DCT 0/DDT - Result - T = 10 K - \u03C6 = 1.0 - DCT 10-40 - t = 2000 s.dat')
file_name_3 = str(u'./data/DDT - T = 10 K/DDT - T = 10 K - \u03C6 = 1.0/DDT - T = 10 K - \u03C6 = 1.0 - DCT 0/DDT - Result - T = 10 K - \u03C6 = 1.0 - DCT 10-40 - t = 3000 s.dat')
file_names.append(file_name_1)
file_names.append(file_name_2)
file_names.append(file_name_3)

file_names = np.asarray(file_names)
for file_name in file_names:
    phi = re.findall(ur"(?:\u03C6 = )([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)", file_name)
    print phi
```

But it is not able to extract the required values. How to extract numbers just succeeding a unicode character with regex in Python?

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/tCoXwJ.

Comment: If you remove str it works. Is it possible to get the results with str?

Comment: I do not know why you need `str()` here. The strings contain a Unicode letter, and the `u''` prefix is required. If you need to convert to Unicode, use `unicode(text, 'utf-8')`.

Comment: Could you please explain what your real scenario is.

Comment: If you want to keep `str`, you may want to remove the `u` prefixes to deal with byte strings? See https://ideone.com/D2QHx5.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just mix up the byte strings and Unicode strings. You need to make sure you deal with one type of strings when processing text, you cannot mix them up. So, if you need to keep the byte strings, do not use `u''` prefix from your strings, and keep `str('...')`:

```
file_name_1 = str('./data/DDT - T = 10 K/DDT - T = 10 K - \u03C6 = 1.0/DDT - T = 10 K - \u03C6 = 1.0 - DCT 0/DDT - Result - T = 10 K - \u03C6 = 1.0 - DCT 10-40 - t = 1000 s.dat')
              ^^^ ^
...
phi = re.findall(r"(?:\u03C6 = )([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)", file_name)
                 ^
```

And you will get the output as `['1.0', '1.0', '1.0']`. See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/D2QHx5).

Else, you need to remove the `str()` and keep `u''` prefix to work with the Unicode strings. Do not forget to keep the `u` prefix with the regex pattern, too, then.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Unicode strings.  Here's a simplified version that works.  If you save the source as UTF-8 and declare the source encoding you can use the actual `φ` character as well, but using Unicode escapes works, too.

```
#encoding:utf8
import re

file_names = [u'./data/DDT - T = 10 K/DDT - T = 10 K - φ = 1.0/DDT - T = 10 K - φ = 1.0 - DCT 0/DDT - Result - T = 10 K - φ = 1.0 - DCT 10-40 - t = 1000 s.dat',
              u'./data/DDT - T = 10 K/DDT - T = 10 K - φ = 1.0/DDT - T = 10 K - φ = 1.0 - DCT 0/DDT - Result - T = 10 K - φ = 1.0 - DCT 10-40 - t = 2000 s.dat',
              u'./data/DDT - T = 10 K/DDT - T = 10 K - φ = 1.0/DDT - T = 10 K - φ = 1.0 - DCT 0/DDT - Result - T = 10 K - φ = 1.0 - DCT 10-40 - t = 3000 s.dat']
for file_name in file_names:
    phi = re.findall(ur'(?:φ = )([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)', file_name)
    print phi
```

Output:

```
[u'1.0', u'1.0', u'1.0']
[u'1.0', u'1.0', u'1.0']
[u'1.0', u'1.0', u'1.0']
```

Note: the `reload(sys)` trick should never be used and was useless in this case anyway. Python 2.X libraries expect the default encoding to be `ascii`.  Changing it can cause bugs.  No reason to use `numpy` as well.